# Newbie, need help in designing test plan in jmeter for concurrent API calls

Tags: jmeter

We have a Rest Server talking to 128 devices. I need to send 10 API calls to each device and to all 128 devices at the same time. So the Rest server needs to handle 1280 at a time every 15 mins. I am using `jmeter` and can create 1280 threads to make each API call unique to go to all 128 devices manually. Is there a better way to do it other than manually typing and populating the threads?

Basically, I am looking to automate the process of creating the threads through a script and load the jmx to GUI, or better/faster way using GUI itself

Comment: Basically, I am looking to automate the process of creating the threads through a script and load the jmx to GUI, or better/faster way using GUI itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the following test elements are being used:

1. Recording: using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for automation of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers creation. The idea is that you execute your test scenario on mobile device and JMeter captures the traffic and creates the relevant requests.
2. [Parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide): if your want to use different data for different virtual users you can configure JMeter to read it from external sources (files, databases, etc.), the most commonly used test element is [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer): this guy ensures that samplers it its scope are executed at exactly the same moment. Normally JMeter executes requests as fast as it can, but it doesn't guarantee that requests will happen at exactly the same moment unless you use the Syncrhonizing Timer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it is only reading one device and fire one request per thread, basically doing consecutive rather than concurrent. It is a challenge and jmeter don't have the capacity to read from a file and make all the requests concurrent. For the time being I will create 1000+ threads manually with each API request and fire them as concurrent.